# Previous And Next Month buttons not working for PHP Calendar

Tags: php, calendar

I'm working on a strictly PHP calendar and my previous and next buttons aren't working properly. So far, i just have the month, year, and a small form. I do not have the actual calendar yet. The form consists of a button that brings the calendar to the current month and year. A dropdown box each for months, and for years, with a submit button allowing the user to select the month and year. Then two buttons after for going to the previous / next month. My code is:

```
<?php
$month_numbers = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);
$months_of_year = array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December");
$days_of_week = array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday");
$month = ($_GET['m']) ? $_GET['m'] : date("n");
$current_month = date("n");
$year = ($_GET['y']) ? $_GET['y'] : date("Y");
$current_year = date("Y");
$previous_month = ($month - 1);
$next_month = ($month + 1);
if($month == 0)
{
  $month = 12;
  $year--;
}
if($month == 13)
{
  $month = 1;
  $year++;
}
$month_name = $months_of_year[$month - 1];
$first_day_of_month = new DateTime();
$first_day_of_month -> setDate($year,$month,1);
$first_day_of_month = $first_day_of_month -> format("w");
echo("<form name = 'formCalendar' id = 'formCalendar' action = 'index.php?' method = 'get'>");
echo("  <table border = '1' cellspacing = '0' cellpadding = '2'>");
echo("    <thcolspan = '7'>
            {$month_name} {$year}
            <span class = 'formTopRight'>
              <input type = 'button' value = 'Today' onclick = 'location=\"index.php?m={$current_month}&y={$current_year}\"'/>
              <select name = 'm' id = 'selMonth'>");
for($a = 0; $a < count($months_of_year); $a++)
{
  echo("        <option value = '{$month_numbers[$a]}'>{$months_of_year[$a]}</option>");
}
echo("        </select>");
echo("        <select name = 'y' id = 'selYear'>");
for($b = ($current_year - 10); $b <= ($current_year + 10); $b++)
{
  echo("        <option value = '{$b}'>{$b}</option>");
}
echo("        </select>");
echo("        <input type = 'submit' name = 'dateChange' id = 'dateChange' value = 'Go'/>");
echo("        <input type = 'button' name = 'prev' value = '<<' onclick = 'location=\"index.php?m={$previous_month}&y={$year}\"'/>");
echo("        <input type = 'button' name = 'next' value = '>>' onclick = 'location=\"index.php?m={$next_month}&y={$year}\"'/>");
echo("  </table>");
echo("<form>");
?>
```

I have it uploaded in a test file on my website at [www.rgbwebd.net/tests](http://www.rgbwebd.net/tests) so you can see for yourselves what its doing.

Comment: Exactly what is the problem you're having? Clicking the `>>` and `<<` buttons on your website do roughly what I would expect.

Comment: add some description on what it's supposed to do and what it is doing, rather than having us try to figure out what your problem is.

Comment: When the previous button is clicked, it alternates between February and January. When the next button is clicked, it doesn't start all over at January and go up from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple fix is to also calculate if you need to use the previous year when going back as you already do this when going forward.

You can utilize `$previous_year` and use that instead of `$year`.

As such

```
'location=\"index.php?m={$previous_month}&y={$previous_year}\"'/>");
```

and make the calucation like you do at the top.

```
$previous_month = ($month - 1);
$previous_year = $year;
$next_month = ($month + 1);
if($month == 0)
{
  $month = 12;
  $year--;
}
if($month == 13)
{
  $month = 1;
  $year++;
}
if($previous_month == 0)
{
  $previous_month = 12;
  $previous_year--;
}
```

**EDIT**

You should not be using one variable and modifying it early on to support two different actions. As such, you use `$month` to fill in previous and next buttons. You should seperate them into `$next_month; $next_year;` and `$previous_month; $previous_year;` (for next and previous button). Also, you could probably look into the [PHP Date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and use methods to add/subtract a month and format the output.

Comment: That works great! What I did, was I deleted the if $month conditions and changed it to previous_month as well as next_month. I think that's what I was doing wrong.